# Going against the limits of language

Tags: philosophy-of-language, wittgenstein, analytic-philosophy, language, natural-language

I vaguely remember a sentence of Wittgenstein which was about the duty of philosophy: that is, to go against the limits of the language. This was in his late period of philosophy.

What is the precise quote, and which work of him contains it?

When I search for this, always the classical quote from the Tractatus comes up, that the limits of my language are the limits of my world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for section 119 of *Philosophical Investigations*:-

119. The results of philosophy are the discovery of some piece of plain
     nonsense and the bumps that the understanding has got by running up
     against the limits of language. They - these bumps - make us see the
     value of that discovery.

ADDED LATER

You will find a large collection of quotations from all of Wittgenstein's writings, including disputed, misattributed and quotes about Wittgenstein, at [Wittgenstein - Wikequote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Ludwig_Wittgenstein). I didn't find any likely candidates for you there. (I can't assess how reliable it is.)